# How to iterate over this particular type of Dictionary<int, Result>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of results from the Database that I keep in a `Dictionary<int, Result>()`.

The Result class I have is:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string something { get; set; }
public string somethingtwo { get; set; }
public string somethingthree { get; set; }
public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public bool somethingfour { get; set; }
```

So, the `Dictionary<int, Result>` has many Results inside and I'd like to iterate over them. How an I do this? I've tried a few ways, but even I knew they wouldn't work.

I would like to do something like this:

```
foreach(var result in resultDict)
{
   mynewstring = result.Location;
   mynewstringtwo = result.Posted;
   // etc etc.
}
```

Comment: The first way, which I thought was the right way, is at the bottom of my question. Granted, it wasn't there when you asked - I forgot to add what I tried until you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dcitionary has a ValueCollection called Values, so the code would be:

```
foreach (Result r in dict.Values)
{
    mynewstring = result.Location;
    mynewstringtwo = result.Posted;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach(var kvp in resultsDict) {
    //Do somethign with kvp
    UseResult(kvp.Value); //kvp.Value is a Result object
    UseKey(kvp.Key); //kvp.Key is the integer key you access it with
}
```

In the above code `kvp` is a `KeyValuePair<int, Result>`. You can access the `Key` and `Value` properties to get the integer key of the `Dictionary` and the `Result` value associated with that `Key`.  I'll leave it as an excercise/guessing game for you to figure out which property is which! ;-)

As @Wiktor mentions, you can also access the dictionary's `Values` and `Keys` collections to do the same thing, but retrieve a sequence of `int` or `Value` properties instead.

Alternatives using the other collections:

```
foreach(var val in resultsDict.Values) {
    // The key is not accessible immediately,
    // you have to examine the value to figure out the key
    UseResult(val); //val is a value.
}

foreach(var key in resultsDict.Keys) {
    //The value isn't directly accessible, but you can look it up.
    UseResult(resultsDict[key]);
    UseKey(key);
}
```

Comment: @Jason, Yup, it does work, you didn't read the paragraph after my example.  I quote: "In the above code kvp is a `KeyValuePair<int, Result>. You can access the `Key` and `Value` properties to get the integer key of the `Dictionary` and the `Result` value associated with that `Key`

Answer (score 1):

```
var dictionary = ...;
foreach ( var result in dictionary.Values )
{
   ...
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Good call. Didn't think of that.

Comment: I think this is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Values` property to iterate over the values of a `Dictionary` (see also the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx)).

Code example:

```
// Your dictionary
var myResultDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Result>();

foreach (var item in myResultDictionary.Values)
{
    // "item" holds a Result object
    // Do something with item
}
```

You can also regularly loop over your `Dictionary`, however `item` will be a `KeyValuePair` ([MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42)) object. You can access the value with the `Value` property on the variable item.

Code example:

```
// Your dictionary
var myResultDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Result>();

foreach (var item in myResultDictionary)
{
    // "item" holds a KeyValuePair<int, Result> object
    // You can access the value (a Result object) by calling "item.Value"
    // Do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over Dictionary.Values, which would be like any other `IEnumerable<Result>`

Or, you can iterate over Dictionary, which is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Result>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Result> item in dictionary)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,result> keyValue in yourDictionary)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(keyValue.Value);
    //or
    Debug.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
}
```

or the same thing, but using var:

```
foreach(var keyValue in yourDictionary)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(keyValue.Value);
    //or
    Debug.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
}
```

^^ same thing, but var dynamically figures out its own type

or you can do this, if you just need the result:

```
foreach(var result in yourDictionary.Values)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) on the Dictionary:

`foreach (var keyValue in dictionary)
{
//Use key value here 
}`